# Cannot replace by range

Tags: pandas, replace, data-science

Below code is working fine but it replacing for specific range if I want to replace between(30001-35000) its showing error:

```
df['Msrp'] = np.where(df['Msrp'].between (25001,30000), 'F', df['Msrp'])
print(df)
df['Msrp'] = np.where(df['Msrp'].between (30001,35000), 'G', df['Msrp'])
print(df)


                    Vin        MakeDescr            SeriesDescr   Msrp
0     2HNYD2H23BH516418            ACURA                    MDX  42580
1     JH4CU2F67AC034248            ACURA                    TSX      F
2     WAUBFAFL3AN022431             AUDI                     A4  32350
3     WBAVC93507K030197              BMW               3 Series  34300
4     1D3HV18P49S803785      DODGE TRUCK     Ram 1500 Pickup-V8  32695
5     2C4RC1BG0CR187071         CHRYSLER      Town & Country-V6      F
```

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for replace by multiple boolean mask:

```
m1 = df['Msrp'].between (25001,30000)
m2 = df['Msrp'].between (30001,35000)

df['Msrp'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['F', 'G'], default='not match')
```

Problem of your code is after first `np.where` get mixed values in `Msrp` column - numeric with `F`, so second `np.where` raise error.